# Delete Cell based off another Cell that is a date

Tags: excel, vba

Working in Excel VBA.
I'm trying to delete a cell, if there is a date in another cell via VBA.
Or another way to put it, I'm trying to delete a cell, if another cell has ANYthing in it. (As it's either a date, or not.)

Here's my code - I just don't know how to recognise any date in the cell.

```
Sub Upload1ClearADP()
Dim LastRow As Long, x As Long
LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

For x = 2 To LastRow
    If Cells(x, "G").Value = "Date" Then
        Cells(x, "U").ClearContents
    End If
Next x

End Sub
```

Comment: `If Not IsEmpty(Cells(x, "G")) Then` perhaps. Or just clear the whole column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're currently checking for a string `Date`, not technically an actual date.

Here's your code written to check if it's a date OR is empty:

```
Sub Upload1ClearADP()
Dim LastRow As Long, x As Long
LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

For x = 2 To LastRow
    If IsDate(Cells(x, "G").Value) or Cells(x, "G") <> "" Then
        Cells(x, "U").ClearContents
    End If
Next x

End Sub
```

Edit: As @Harun24HR points out in the comments, the `IsDate()` is unnecessary, since you check if the cell is not empty (`<> ""`).  I just wanted to put it there to introduce the [`IsDate()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/isdate-function) function.

Edit 2: You can also use `SpecialCells()` to do the clearing in one line:

```
Sub Upload1ClearADP()
Dim LastRow As Long
LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Dim dataRng As Range
Set dataRng = Range(Cells(2, "G"), Cells(LastRow, "G"))
' Use 14 because it's 14 columns to the right from
' Column G to U
dataRng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Offset(0, 14).ClearContents

' If you have formulas *and* constants in column G, use:
' Union(dataRng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants), _
'     dataRng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)).Offset(0,14).ClearContents

End Sub
```

Comment: Then only one condition `Cells(x, "G") <> ""` is enough.

Comment: @Harun24HR agreed, just wanted to show the `isDate()` function too.

Comment: @Campbell - See my edit, the second version might be of interest too.